# Relative size and scaling of points vs. axis text

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

My question is related to the size of geometries and texts (in axes of a chart). I'm trying to export a chart with the size of the font must be approximately to 12 points, so I've declared `size = 12/.pt` in `element_text()`. To exemplify, I wrote the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

chart = ggplot(diamonds)+
  geom_point(aes(x, price), size = 1, shape = "circle open")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 12/.pt),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12/.pt))

chart
```

[image: chart]

Since `ggplot2` works with millimeters in its units, if I understod, declaring `geom_point(size = 1)`, and `theme(axis.title / axis.text = element_text(size = 12/.pt))`, the size of the points should must be smaller than the text, right? Why is this not the case?

Comment: The problem here is that geoms scale differently than text.  Ultimately, the look of your plot will depend on the sizing of the elements in the code, but also on the dimensions and resolution of your graphics device.  Resize your output window and you can see this working: text doesn't really scale, but geoms do.

Comment: @chemdork123, thank you by the comment. I noticed what you said, and searching here did I see that in element_text() function the argument "size" is the text size in points, in the new release of ggplot2, and in the geometries refers to the size in mm. So, thank you.